# Push Notification in Background not working iOS12 Swift4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented push notification by firebase. Not able to get notifications from background. Having following code in my App delegate,

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
     let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
         sleep(3)
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

      UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
  FirebaseApp.configure()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Message Data", remoteMessage.appData)

    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }

}
```

And getting print for Message Data at did receive remote Notification

```
Message Data [AnyHashable("from"): 459345502087, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): www.rwdev.com.TravelSheriff2.1, AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = "Notifications ";
    e = 1;
    tag = "campaign_collapse_key_4509884114250587926";
    title = "Travel Sheriff ";
}]
```

But I am not able to get push notifications while background and foreground. Even not getting "Message Data" print while app in background.
(Note:Please don't come up with previous stack overflow links and answers have already tried most of them..didnt work out..)

Comment: can you tell me your project setup Capabilities in Push Notification On or not.

Comment: @ Pradip Patel, yes, its set On in my capabilities for background modes and push notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey @Aleesha use the request identifier.
I give you example down below follow the code, i hope its worked.

```
//MARK:- USER NOTIFICATION DELEGATE

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    print(notification.request.content.userInfo)

    if notification.request.identifier == "rig"{
        completionHandler( [.alert,.sound,.badge])
    }else{
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

}



func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    //Handle the notification
    completionHandler(
        [UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert,
         UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound,
         UNNotificationPresentationOptions.badge])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print(deviceTokenString)

}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

    print(userInfo)

    switch application.applicationState {
    case .active:
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        if let title = userInfo["title"]
        {
            content.title = title as! String
        }
        if let title = userInfo["text"]
        {
            content.body = title as! String
        }
        content.userInfo = userInfo
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:"rig", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let getError = error {
                print(getError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    case .inactive:
        break
    case .background:
        break
    }



}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("i am not available in simulator \(error)")
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")

}
```

Comment: Excellent piece of code. It works both in Foreground and background notifications,, Thanks a lot..